# AWS Cognito: auth page not showing up, DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN from hosted UI URL

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, domain, authentication, 500-error

Here is the url I am navigating to:

http​​s://​auth.[domain].com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[id here]&response_type=code&scope=email+openid+phone&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F[domain]%2F[page]

The error is:

This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in auth.[domain].com.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Hosted UI status: "Available"

The link: https://[domain].auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com returns a blank page (expected)

The link "http​​s://​auth.[domain].com" also returns a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error (I set this up as a custom domain in addition to the Cognito domain).

Any ideas as to what's causing this or how to fix it? I have waited a long time (i.e., potentially for propagation) and no change in behavior has occurred. This is odd because I've set up similar things with no problem.

Update: I've just noticed that https://[name I gave Cognito].auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=[client ID]&response_type=code&scope=email+openid+phone&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F[domain].com%2F[page] will resolve to the sign in page, and works correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Ensure that the root domain (or the level one up) has a CNAME record with the target given to you in the app integration page. Wait for it to propagate.